# close jframe without stop program

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, swing

a eclipse program by java language have several `JFrame`'s and some `JFrame`'s are called any `JFrame`'s or `Class`'s as `Thread`.
problem are when one of JFrame's need to close then all of `JFrame`'s closed and thread's will be started as that `JFrame` incomplete closed.
one offer is use `f.setVisible(false);` but this is not good because in through time i have many `JFrame`'s  because `JFrame`'s are called as:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();//make new JFrame
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: See [The use of multiple JFrames, Good / Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice). And for better help sooner please post a [mcve]

Comment: Also check: [JFrame#dispose()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) and [JFrame#DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)

Comment: Set the default close behavior. https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp310/JavaResources/frame_close.html